# Calculate price to earning and price to sale value for given dataset

Tags: stocks, price-earnings-ratio

Consider this dataset - https://www.google.com/finance/historical?q=NYSE%3ABME&ei=DSIeVtGMAYrvuATEsZfACA

I want to calculate Price/Earning i.e. latest PRICE/(NETINC MRT/SHARESWADIL MRT) for 11 Nov

```
i.e. 42.41(Closing price on 11th Nov )/ (NETINC MRT/SHARESWADIL MRT)
```

I checked definitions for NETINC ANDSHARESWADIL but could not understand how to get this value for dataset. Any help for this?

similarly Price/Sale ratio is                                                                                                Latest PRICE/(REVENUE MRT/SHARESWADIL MRT)

```
i.e. 42.41 / (REVENUE MRT/SHARESWADIL MRT)
```

How to get REvenue MRT and Shareswadil MRT?

Answer (score 1):

## Price to Earnings and Price to Sale Calculation

Too calculate these values, information contained in the company's financial statements (income, balance, or cashflow) will be needed along with the price.

Google finance does not maintain this information for [BME](https://www.google.com/finance?q=NYSE%3ABME&fstype=ii).  You will need to find another source for this information or analyze another another symbol's financial section ([BAC for example](https://www.google.com/finance?q=NYSE%3ABAC&fstype=ii)).